# Using pointers in if statement for linked list

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list

I'm trying to program a card game in C using a double linked list to represent a deck. I've got the list and everything, and it shuffles like it's supposed to at the beginning, but the deck is supposed to be re-shuffled whenever it's within one round of the bottom of the deck (i.e. the number of the next card in the list is 49 or higher). Everything works, except for the one line command that's supposed to determine when it reshuffles.

The problem code in question is:

```
if((game->nextPos == 52ndCard) || (game->nextPos == 51stCard) || (game->nextPos == 50thCard) || (game->nextPos == 49thCard) || (game->nextPos == NULL))
```

In this snippet, game, nextPos, and NthCard are all pointers (with the NthCard pointers set to the last four cards in the deck, reflective of the name; I know those are working, because my printCard function prints out the correct cards after the those pointers have been assigned).

I've tried different permutations of games to get the position of the next card to land on 49, 50, 51, 52, and null, and none of these conditions trigger the if statement, which leads me to believe that I need to change the syntax of the if statement. What is the proper syntax to use here?

Comment: show some code padewan.

Comment: Are the `NthCard` pointers of the same type as `nextPos`? If so than the problem is not the `if` statement.

Comment: There isn't enough code here for us to be able to help.  Assuming you have rational definitions for the names shown as `52ndCard` etc. (which aren't valid C identifiers or numbers), then the problem isn't in the `if` statement.  It is curious that you're using a linked list and also positions; are you sure you wouldn't do better with an array?  Anyway, please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) and add that code to the question.

Comment: You can simply follow up to three `nextPos` pointers to determine whether the pack is nearly empty.  If you hit `NULL` then you need to reshuffle, otherwise you can go another round.

Comment: To follow up on paddy's comment, if((game->nextPos == NULL) || (game->nextPos->nextPos == NULL) || (game->nextPos->nextPos->nextPos == NULL) ...